# Comparing two arrays for login form

Tags: java, arrays

I currently have two arrays containing usernames and passwords.

```
   String[] UsernameArray = {"John","Per","Daniel","Jonathan"};
   String[] PasswordArray = {"Davis","Harring","Smith","West"};'
```

Now i have an if statement looking like this:

```
if(Arrays.asList(UsernameArray).contains(LoginPanel.Username)&& Arrays.asList(PasswordArray).contains(LoginPanel.Password)) {
                   //Do something
    }
```

Everything is working fine, except for the fact i only want respective people to use their respective last names as passwords. I want for example the username to be "John" and the password to be "Davis" ONLY.

As of now if i enter John and then enter the second persons last name "Harring" i get "Success!" and is logged on. How can i change this so the persons passwords can only be their own lastname and not anyone else's?

Comment: Loop over the array and check if the username given is right, save the index of that username and check if the password at that index is the same entered by the user.

Comment: @BackSlash you should elaborate (with some code) and write an answer

Comment: @clcto Right, did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the strings are at the same index in their respective arrays. Use the `indexOf` method:

```
if (Arrays.asList(UsernameArray).contains(LoginPanel.Username) &&    
    Arrays.asList(PasswordArray).contains(LoginPanel.Password) && 
    //this way me make sure the username and password are at the same position. 
    Arrays.asList(UsernameArray).indexOf(LoginPanel.Username) == Arrays.asList(PasswordArray).indexOf(LoginPanel.Password) 
)
{
                   //Do something
}
```

You may want to use a few local variables to avoid so many calls to `Arrays.asList`, which will create a new list every time you call it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ArrayList`s for that purpose, it's a waste of memory, you can use just  arrays.

Loop over the array and check if the username given is right, save the index of that username and check if the password at that index is the same entered by the user. Something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<usernameArray.length; i++) {
    if (LoginPanel.username.equals(usernameArray[i]) && LoginPanel.password.equals(passwordArray[i])) {
        //right credentials
    }
}
```

**To be clear:** `inputUser` and `inputPassword` are username and password entered by the user

**Note:** As you can see, i used `usernameArray`, `passwordArray`, `LoginPanel.username` and `LoginPanel.password` with **lowercase u and p**: this is because of java naming conventions, you should start variable names with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf:

```
List<String> usernames = Arrays.asList(UsernameArray);
if (usernames.contains(LoginPanel.Username) &&
    PasswordArray[usernames.indexOf(LoginPanel.Username)].equals(LoginPanel.Password)) {
        // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API documentation

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

In your case, `UsernameArray` contains **John** and `PasswordArray` contains **Harring** and hence `Arrays.asList(UsernameArray).contains(LoginPanel.Username)&& Arrays.asList(PasswordArray).contains(LoginPanel.Password)` returns true.

You can use a Map of user name password like

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("John","Davis");
```

and then this can be validated

```
String password= map.get(LoginPanel.Username);
if(LoginPanel.Password.equals(password0){
        //Do something
}
```

Please note that in a real web application, password would be stored encrypted in some data store and not in a program.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
for(int i=0;i< UserNameArray.length; i++){
    if(UserNameArray[i].equals(LoginPanel.Username)&& PasswordArray[i].equals(LoginPanel.Password)){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is that

```
public class LoginTestEasy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] UsernameArray = {"John","Per","Daniel","Jonathan"};
    String[] PasswordArray = {"Davis","Harring","Smith","West"};

    String loginToCheck = "John";
    String passwordToCheck = "Herring";


    boolean loggedIn = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < UsernameArray.length; i++) {
        String currentLogin = UsernameArray[i];
        String currentPass = PasswordArray[i];

        if(currentLogin.equals(loginToCheck) && passwordToCheck.equals(currentPass)) {
            loggedIn = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Is logged in: " + loggedIn);
}
}
```

but the better way is to join login and password pair in single object. smth like

```
class LoginData {
    String login;
    String pass;

    LoginData(String login, String pass) {
        this.login = login;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
}
```

and then to loop among them.